# SQLAlchemy use calculated column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want some code like below:

```
distance = (Robot.pose_x)**2 + (Robot.pose_y)**2
robot_filtered = session.query(Robot).filter(distance > 100).all()
```

But it gives `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'InstrumentedAttribute' and 'int'`

I know why it causes error, but I want such solution.

Is there better way to go with filter or order with pow calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sqlalchemy.func` will likely do the job, I've never done this so you'll have to test the exact syntax, but it should be something like this:

```
distance = func.pow(Robot.pose_x, 2) + func.pow(Robot.pose_y, 2)
```